# Can buildozer made android apps use glob and os modules?

Tags: python, glob, buildozer

So at the moment in try to figure out why is my small player i wrote in kivy crashes on start. It says build successful and all modules seem to work separately in other tests (except for glob) but this one is pure python as far as i know.

here's my code

```
import glob
import kivy
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import random
import os
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])




class PageI(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__( **kwargs)
        self.cols = 3
        self.state = False
        
        
        self.music = glob.glob('/Phone/reMusic/*.mp3')#glob.glob('music\\*.mp3')
        
            



        self.currname = self.music[0]
        self.lasttime = 0
        self.currsound = SoundLoader.load(self.currname)

        fillclr = (round(random.random(),4), round(random.random(),4), round(random.random(),4), 1)

        SR = Button(text='forward')
        SR.bind(on_press=self.switchoR)
        self.add_widget(SR)
        placeholder = Label()
        self.add_widget(placeholder)

        SL = Button(text='backward')
        SL.bind(on_press=self.switchoL)
        self.add_widget(SL)

        placeholder = Label()
        self.add_widget(placeholder)

        self.PP = Button(on_press = self.switchostate)
        self.add_widget(self.PP)

        placeholder = Label()
        self.add_widget(placeholder)

        placeholder = Label()
        self.add_widget(placeholder)

        self.showcase = Label(text=self.currname)
        self.add_widget(self.showcase)

    def PPcontrol(self):
        if not self.currsound.state == 'play':
            self.currsound.play()
            self.currsound.seek(self.lasttime)
        else:
            self.lasttime = int(self.currsound.get_pos())
            self.currsound.stop()




    def switchostate(self,instance):
        self.PPcontrol()

    def showsitch(self):
        self.showcase.text = self.currname

    def switchoR(self,instance):
        instance.background_color = (round(random.random(),4), round(random.random(),4), round(random.random(),4), 1)
        ind = self.music.index(self.currname)
        if ind+1 > len(self.music)-1:
            self.currname = self.music[ind - len(self.music) + 1]
        else:
            self.currname = self.music[ind + 1]
        self.lasttime = 0
        self.currsound.stop()
        self.currsound = SoundLoader.load(self.currname)
        self.currsound.play()

        self.showsitch()




    def switchoL(self,instance):
        instance.background_color = (round(random.random(),4), round(random.random(),4), round(random.random(),4), 1)
        ind = self.music.index(self.currname)
        if ind - 1 < 0:
            self.currname = self.music[len(self.music) - 2]
        else:
            self.currname = self.music[ind - 1]
        self.lasttime = 0
        self.currsound.stop()
        self.currsound = SoundLoader.load(self.currname)
        self.currsound.play()

        self.showsitch()




class Applet(App):
    def build(self):
        self.dircheck()
        self.p = PageI()
        return self.p

    def dircheck(self):
        try:
            if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'\\music')):
                os.mkdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'\\music'))
        except: None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    apper = Applet()
    apper.run()
```

ik its quite messy but as you can see i tried both creating directories and accessing premade one.
and well, im not sure why it dies, i made sure it had all perms in spec file as well.

Comment: you can try to use `try/except` and save exception in file/log to get some information. You can also save other information in `log` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed.